# Is it possible to set fixed DLL search path in VisualStudio application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dll-search-path

I have a Qt/VisualStudio application which should start from a removable device without installation. I want to place in the root directory only the executable and all the required DLLs in in a directory "data".

The executable should load the DLLs from "data", but no path to "data" should be set before. The DLL search-path should be hard coded in the exe and it should be (only) ".\data"

Is it possible? I'm using VS2008. I've read the documantation on each linker-parameter, but have not identified a proper yet.

Comment: Can't a launcher help you?

Comment: I think manifest files can do this (am not sure): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375365(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Link everything as [/delayload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf3f62bz(v=vs.90).aspx) and have the [helper function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds(v=vs.90).aspx) `LoadLibrary` the DLLs from the "data" directory.

Comment: You want to put *code* in a directory named "data"??  Bit of a toss up whose going to hate that more, your client's IT staff is the one you shouldn't ignore.  But you'll surely hate writing the manifest first.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  DLLs can be data files.  That's the whole point of options like `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`.

Comment: @mvidelgauz Currently I do it with a launcher written in c# - a simple application without a console and a window which sets the path and starts my main application. Unfortunatelly, on Windows 10 the .NET seems to be missing. And I don't know how to write a launcher without Qt or C# which won't shot the DOS-console

Comment: I see you have very good C++ knowledge. Writing a simple app with native Win32 API (using VS, free version if you don't have a paid one) in plain C that will serve as launcher will take ~15 minutes.... (Yes I paid attention to _"which won't shot DOS console"_)

Comment: @mvidelgauz: good Idea, I'll go for that. Seems to be more straight forward than modifying manifest. Hopefully it's also easy to assign a custom icon to the application.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mvidelgauz suggested, I've implemented a launcher using winapi. It was my first native winapi project, but it took indeed only halh an hour to implement.

1. I created a default Win32 project in VS2008.
2. In `BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)`, removed the lines:

   ```
   //ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   //UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   ```
3. And then instead of them, I added:

   ```
   SetCurrentDirectory( L"MyPath" );
   ShellExecute(hWnd, NULL, L"MyApp.exe", L"-l", NULL, SW_HIDE);
   DestroyWindow(hWnd);
   ```

Comment: You don't need (and in fact, shouldn't use) the window. Delete all of the code that registers a window class, creates a window, and so on. All you need is literally the `wWinMain` function with two function calls: `SetCurrentDirectory` and `ShellExecute`. The `hWnd` parameter for `ShellExecute` can (and in this case, *should*) be `NULL`, meaning that the operation is not associated with a window.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it.